# Python multi thread program with maximum threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multi threaded python application
written like this:

```
start=time.time()
for i in ids:           
    t=Thread(target=parseRows,args=(i,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
end=time.time()-start
print('====================================================')
print('Total time : '+ str(end))
```

but when I see my threads in task manager just 8 threads or maximum 12 threads
but there are there are 44000 items in ids list and I want to see more more more than 12 threads
in task manager which work on parseRows methods.

I've used t.join() because of waiting for all threads to finish and count how much time it totaly takes
to get all threads done the job

whats the problem?

Comment: put t.join() in its own loop. join() waits until the thread terminates.

Comment: @dede what do you mean its own loop?it's in the loop

Comment: append t to a list in your loop. Then use another loop, that runs over this list and call join for each element.

Comment: @dede will you put your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
import threading
import time

def parseRows(i):
  print "%d\n"%(i,),
  time.sleep(0.1)

ids=range(100)

start=time.time()
ts=list()
for i in ids:           
    t=threading.Thread(target=parseRows,args=(i,))
    ts.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in ts:
    t.join()

end=time.time()-start
print('====================================================')
print('Total time : '+ str(end))
```

And also try it, after putting a comment-symbol in front of the second for-statement :-)

with

```
#for t in ts:
```

I get:

```
Total time : 10.0569360256
```

And without, I get

```
Total time : 0.117892026901
```